# Can I limit a view mode to show on the "Manage Display" settings page for only one node type?

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a module that creates a custom node type ("answers") and a custom view mode ("answers_full_node") for that node type.

Now, when I look at the "Manage Display" settings page for *any* node type, the custom view mode is available.

Is there a way I can restrict it so that it shows up only for my custom node type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, view modes are per entity type, not per bundle.